# I need to renumber the ID's of my posts to start at a higher number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have been rebuilding my site in a local host environment (Wamp)and have made a number of posts in the new site. I would like to import the database from the online iteration of my site but I am concerned that there will be conflicts with the ID's.

My online site has ID's numbering up to 1029. Is there a way of renumbering the ID's on the new (offline) site to start from, say, 1040 in order that there are no duplicates?

Comment: Before you do anything make sure you have a backup of your local wampserver database

Answer (score 1):

you can use

UPDATE table SET column = column + 1040;

next id would be 1041

hope you have marked field as auto_increment

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I have managed to do what I needed and the localhost is running perfectly.  I am just about to upload to my host server.